# Iphone 2D app suggestion

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, 2d, quartz-graphics

I need to develop a Iphone 2D app for school project. I don't have object C and C++ background. I just go through the Iphone App develop process on-line. Any suggestions to quickly build a 2D iphone app?

Should I must use either Opengl-es or Quartz? Is there any framework could help to quickly draw line and curve with 2D?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Chris In what was can this possibly be homework?

Comment: Not HW. It is a project based on an essay to implement a graphic algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) maybe? (though you will need to learn some objective-c)

[GCDrawKit](http://apptree.net/drawkit.htm) could be good too if you need more vector-like stuff

Comment: Cocos2d is definitely the way to go for a project like this.

Comment: He does not even have an objective-c background. He should be learning the basics first.

Comment: Could probably pick up bits and pieces on the way, this is just a school project really..

Answer (score 1):

As Ben has said Cocos2d is a good option. And, to extend it a little further for Cocos2D:

int the -(void)draw method:

```
ccDrawLine(startPoint, endPoint);
```

draws a line.

And to draw a curve you can use this function on this website in the cocos2d draw method:

http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2152

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be difficult to "quickly build a 2D iphone app". To do it correctly, you really need to understand how everything works together, or you're likely to have tons of bugs and memory leaks. That said, there are some libraries that can help you do some of the dirty work. For example, there is the [Unity game development tool](http://unity3d.com/unity/). I've used the 3D version, and it runs a bit slower on older phones, but the 2D version should run much faster. There are other dev tools available too, just search google for one that looks appealing.

Comment: @Ben: Yeah, the initial setup takes a bit longer but after that you can accomplish stuff much quicker than you can with lower level code.

Answer (score 0):

Start off by learning objective-c first. Learn to draw using the high level cocoa methods such as NSBezierPath, then move slowly towards Core Graphics(Quartz). Begin by understanding what a graphics context is and how to draw simple objects onto it (i.e. lines, boxes, circles, etc).

I assume you might want to know a bit about animations so learn a bit about Core Animation too.

It's a fun process. Wish you enjoy it.

Comment: Would be enjoyable indeed, but would defeat the "quickly" requirement :)

Comment: I don't need animation in this project.